# Should a servlet explicitly return at the end of doGet/doPost?

Tags: java, servlets, return

Is there any difference between explicitly returning at the end of doGet or doPost-methods, and just letting the method return "by itself"?

```
public void doGet(HttpSerlvetRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    <my code here>
    return;
}

public void doGet(HttpSerlvetRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    <my code here>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. As a regular `void` method, it does not require a `return`

Answer (score 12):

There are however cases where you see the `return` statement in a servlet method which might be at first glance confusing for starters. Here's an example:

```
protected void doPost(request, response) {
    if (someCondition) {
        response.sendRedirect("page");
        return;
    }
    doSomethingElse();
    request.getRequestDispatcher("page").forward(request, response);
}
```

Here the `return` statement is **necessary** because calling a redirect (or forward) does not cause the code to magically jump out of the method block as some starters seem to think. It still continues to run until the end which would cause an `IllegalStateException: response already committed` at the point when the forward is called.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but what else can produce the same effect (the code block after `dispatcher` or `redirect` not getting executed) in a servlet?

Comment: if you return without explicity writing anything to the response does the servlet just send a blank response ?

Answer (score 2):

Utterly unnecessary; doesn't add any style points, either.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference at all, a return is implicit at the end of a method.

Comment: Its only implicit for a `void` method.

Answer (score 0):

No difference at all, the return statement is unnecessary.